# Prevent Jenkins from polling SCM (Git) while build is running

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

Let's say I have a build which takes 5 minutes to run, and SCM polling is set to run every 2 minutes (`H/2 * * * *`). If a commit is pushed, Jenkins polls and finds changes and starts build #1. After 2 minutes have elapsed and build #1 is still running, Jenkins polls *again*, finding the same "change" (which is already being built), and it queues build #2.

I have "do not build concurrently" set for the project.

It appears that the "last built revision" is not updated until the build completes. You can imagine, if I queue up 5-10 different projects around the same time, then Jenkins will slow down (running simultaneous builds from different projects), and polling for each of those projects will continue to add another build for the same commit which is already queued or building.

How do I disable *polling* while the same project is building? (Changing polling to check every 5+ minutes instead is not the proper solution.)

**TL;DR** I don't want my Jenkins projects to poll while they are already building, or a build is queued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fix for this issue other than switching to webhook-based builds, which is what we did, and never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

As of a few years ago the Jenkins project declined to add this feature:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8950 -  disable polling if build is running.

Comment: Hmm. We switched to webhooks anyway because this makes Jenkins unusable. Seems extremely obvious to me that Jenkins should _not_ start a new build for a project if a build is already running for the same commit. But Jenkins would just endlessly queue new builds.